# How can I make a custom configuration section that can contain attributes not defined at compile time?

Tags: c#, configuration, configurationsection

Please note this is not the actual case, but only a simplified example.

Lets say I have a Log class, then Sub classed from that I have a file log and a email log.
Now lets say that I want to have a configuration section such as

```
   Logs>
     Log Type="file" fileName="log.txt" Verbosity="3"/>
     Log Type="email" emailAddress="email@server.com" Verbosity="1"/>
   /Logs>
```

Currently I have a solution that will allow

```
   Logs>
     Log Type="file" Verbosity="3"/>
     Log Type="email" Verbosity="1"/>
   /Logs>
```

But as soon as I attempt to add fileName or emailAddress* (this is only an example) I get an error because the configuration section for a base log class does not contain configurationProperties specific to the sub log types. Is there any way that this can be acomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the [OnDeserializeUnrecognizedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement.ondeserializeunrecognizedattribute.aspx) method and store the value in some kind of property bag. If you look at the System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement class in the System assembly you can see it does just that; you'll need to get the framework source or use a decompiler for that.